# Charts or Graphs

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

[image]

I want a chart similar in the image.
Is it possible with google charts or any other jquery chart library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the chart, this code for [google visualization](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart) will do it:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Oranges', 'Apples'],
    ['India',  4,   10],
    ['USA',  2,   3],
    ['Africa',  1,   1],
    ['Russia',  24,  12],
    ['UK',  3,   2],
    ['Spain',  1,   2],
    ['Germany',  3,   3]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {width:600, height:400, isStacked: true}
      );
}
```

<sub>Disclaimer: this is not 3d. I do not believe in 3d graphs for [many reasons](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/excel-3d-charts-charts-with-no-value/)</sub>

Result:

[image: Interactive Chart]

If you absolutely need 3d, you can use the old version of barcharts:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['barchart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Oranges', 'Apples'],
          ['India',  4,   10],
          ['USA',  2,   3],
          ['Africa',  1,   1],
          ['Russia',  24,  12],
          ['UK',  3,   2],
          ['Spain',  1,   2],
          ['Germany',  3,   3]
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
            draw(data,
                 {width:600, height:400, isStacked: true, is3D: true}
            );
      }


      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image: 3d is evil]

I assume the table below isn't needed if the chart is interactive, but you can do that with [this](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#table) if absolutely required.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [highchart plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/). It is a very good plugin for creating any type of chart.

Also see [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/)

But high-chart is pretty good.

**update**

[jchartfx](http://www.jchartfx.com/demo/)

Comment: i saw both plugins but i dint find any exact graph like i want as mentioned above.Can you provide me an example?

Comment: I don't think Highcharts offers 3D charts. I consider that a blessing. 3D charts should be avoided. The 3D effect does not add any value, but instead makes the chart harder to read and interpret.

Comment: ok i don't want 3d chart just the 2d chart will do and table layout below the chart

Comment: see i add a new jquery chart plugin in my answer i think it will fill your requirment

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the google charts api documentation?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

It looks pretty good and it is also interactive.